# Firebase Pagination

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using JSQMessageViewController to create a Chat Application. In that at first I fetch last 25 message and then when user is at top I have to fetch more 25 message above that. I'm doing it by below way but it is returning first 25.  `queryEnding(atValue: self.threadIDs.first!)` is not working. `self.threadIDs.first` contains correct last message's threadId.

```
    let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryEnding(atValue: self.threadIDs.first!).queryLimited(toFirst: 25) // in JSQMessagesLoadEarlierHeaderView
```

This is how I'm fetching data first

```
func observeMessages () {
            let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimited(toLast: 25)
            newMessageRefHandle = messagesQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) -> Void in
                guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
                let key = snapshot.key
                weakSelf.threadIDs.append(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the *next* 25 items, so should use `queryStarting(atValue:`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen snapshot returns null if I use `queryStarting(atValue:`

Comment: `queryEnding(atValue:` returns value but not in the query I wanted.

Comment: That seems unlikely: if you have the last item on the first page as the anchor item and you pass that into `queryStarting(atValue:`, it should return the next batch of items, starting at the anchor item. So there will be a one-item overlap between the pages, but that's about the only problem with this approach. Can you share the minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem you have when using `queryStarting(atValue:`? (hint: use hard-coded values for this and share your JSON as text from your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data))